# JProgressBar doesn't look correct

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, look-and-feel

Even using the following code the JProgressBar I'm using to display the progress of a download is far from the Windows 10 native look: in other programs the green part of the progress bar fills the entire height of the progress bar but in Java it doesn't seem to be the case. Also when updated the progress bar feels very chunky compared to other programs.

Here's how it looks normally
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7ja1.png

In java
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmkNV.png

```java
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
```

the main JFrame of my app

```java
    private JButton button = new JButton("Test");

    private JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();

    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public MainFrame()
    {

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        progressBar.setMinimum(0);
        progressBar.setMaximum(100);
        progressBar.setValue(60);

        progressBar.setEnabled(true);

        progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 25));

        this.panel.add(progressBar);
        this.panel.add(button);

        this.setSize(400, 600);
        this.setContentPane(panel);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: While Swing strives to emulate native controls in its system look-and-feels, there are things which it simply does not get exactly right.  If you want pixel-perfect native controls, you may want to consider using JavaFX rather than Swing.

Comment: One idea is to `progressbar.setStringPainted(true);` and then `progressbar.setBackground(Color.green);`. I know it does not feel windows but fixing it looks like a pain...

Comment: It's still not 100% Windows but it looks 10x times better @GeorgeZ.

Answer (score 2):

This made my progressbar look much better in my opinion.

```
public static Font defaultFont = new Font(Font.decode(null).getName(), Font.PLAIN, 12);
progressbar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
        progressbar.setBackground(new Color(230, 230, 230));
        progressbar.setForeground(new Color(120, 230, 90));
        progressbar.setUI(new BasicProgressBarUI() {
            @Override
            protected Color getSelectionBackground() {
                return new Color(50, 50, 50);
            }

            @Override
            protected Color getSelectionForeground() {
                return new Color(50, 50, 50);
            }
        }
```

Edit: you can optionally use `progressbar.setStringPainted(true)` to show the percentage